# Converting to address payable not working

Tags: solidity, payable, address.transfer

1. 

```
 address payable constant public pillowInc = address(uint160(0x4B38016118FDE970e2371740F849840aEc745c7B));
```

2. 

```
  address payable constant public pillowInc = 0x4B38016118FDE970e2371740F849840aEc745c7B;
```

The compiler is complaining about "TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable."

The above methods are what I found on StackExchange. Can anyone help me get this thing to compile? Compiler version 0.8.10

Answer (score 2):

```
address payable pillowInc = payable(0x4B38016118FDE970e2371740F849840aEc745c7B);
```

This worked.